# How to update clients' Power BI files without ruining their reports?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

We have lots of clients each having a database(all have same structure) on their servers. **I am trying to prepare a base Power BI file** which has the ability to get data from the server and **has business logic** (calculated columns, measures etc.). **But every client needs their own reports.**

I am trying to prepare **Data** and **Relationships** tabs and clients are preparing **Report** tab.

But what if I want to **update the business logic**? How can I update clients' files **without ruining** their already prepared **reports**? Is there an option to **import only business logic** to a file? **Or am I doing wrong with this kind of planning?**

Note: If I rename some columns/measures or make some relationship changes, this would lead errors in some reports. I am aware of this and want to ignore this situation. Even if this happens, some reports may need some attention, still much better than creating all reports in all updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the hack I've described in the comments to this post: http://byobi.com/blog/2016/05/strategic-prototyping-power-bi-desktop-vs-power-pivot/
you can actually "transplant" the model between workbooks.

Note: You have to replace these 3 elements: DataMashup, DataModel and Metadata

anyone spotted a feature-request for this issue in the ideas-section already?: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi

Comment: Thank you for the approach. Replacing DataMashup instead of DataModel is working. If you clearly state this in the answer I would like to accept.

Comment: Updating my comment. Only replacing DataMashup is not importing relationships. Now I saw that DataMashup, DataModel and Metadata files all should be replaced with new ones.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Parameters and the Power BI Desktop Template file for this.  The Parameter value would drive the variations in business logic.  The Template is a Report file emptied of data.  When you/they open it in PBI Desktop, it will ask for the Parameter values (optional) and load all the data.

You would need to change your workflow so that one author maintains all the report pages in the PBIT file.

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/deep-dive-into-query-parameters-and-power-bi-templates/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately the variations are not in the workflow, but in the reports. I am using parameters for connection properties. But my main problem is reports. It is practically not possible to add all reports(all clients' needs) in one file.

Comment: Probably the best you can do is add all the reports as separate pages per client, publish, then go through PBI Web to delete irrelevant pages.